# How to run a foreground task through WinRM / Remote Powershelling

Tags: powershell, azure, protractor, virtual-machine, winrm

I'm trying to incorporate a test suite that runs nightly on an Azure VM.

As of now, I have a Build process using TFS2015 that publishes my test files, starts the VM, and copies the files.

I'm trying to then use the "PowerShell on Target Machine" task to execute a script that launches a batch file.  The reason it'll be executing a batch file is because I can't have the build process wait until that script is finished (it takes around 3 hours for the tasks in the batch file to complete).

My initial logic was to have the powershell script create a task using schtasks.  This part works and the task itself is created on the virtual machine, however, it never runs at the scheduled time.

The other issue is that if I manually create these tasks, the task is executed, but everything is executed in the background.  I need everything to be executed in the foreground.

I'm aware that this is by design since you should not be able to run foreground processes/applications remotely since it isn't "your session".

So the question will remain, are there any work arounds to this?

I'm trying to do launch selenium webservers and then execute protractor automation tests on the virtual machine.  So one batch file starts the selenium server and the second launches protractor with a defined suite.  If these are ran in the background (essentially headless) all my tests break.

Any insight would be helpful, or if I need to expand on my question or provide further details please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this doesn't answer your specific question, but have you looked at [moving your Selenium tests into VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-selenium)? They're officially supported in the build/release pipelines and [other people are taking this approach with protractor here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protractor+vsts) and [elsewhere](http://www.clemensreijnen.nl/post/2016/10/17/CICD-Pipeline-for-Angular2-with-VSTS). People are also [making it work with TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protractor+tfs).